# Using xstring with translator

Tags: xstring, translator

I wrote the following code to extract the first letter of weekdays, as provided by the `translator` package:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xstring}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calendar}

\begin{document}
\StrLeft{\pgfcalendarweekdayname{1}}{1}
\end{document}
```

The output would be "T" (for Tuesday) as expected. I'd like this to work with multilingual documents, so I added the `translator` package and a language option:

```
\documentclass[german]{article}
\usepackage{translator}
\usepackage{xstring}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calendar}

\begin{document}
\StrLeft{\pgfcalendarweekdayname{1}}{1}
\end{document}
```

Compiling the document will now give the following error:

```
! Use of \\translate  doesn't match its definition.
\kernel@ifnextchar ...d@d =#1\def \reserved@a {#2}
                                                  \def \reserved@b {#3}\futu...
l.10 \StrLeft{\pgfcalendarweekdayname{1}}{1}

?
```

Reading the `xstring` documentation, I tried `\noexpandarg`, `\expandarg`, `\normalexpandarg`, but all caused errors.

Is there any way I can get around this?

Comment: This seems to be an expansion problem

Comment: The `\translate` command is not expandable and it can't work with `\StrLeft`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're out of luck. The macro `\pgfcalendarweekdayname` means

```
\translate{%
  \ifcase #1Monday\or Tuesday\or Wednesday\or Thursday\or Friday\or Saturday\or Sunday\fi
}
```

and, without `translator`, `\translate` just returns its argument.

When `translator` is loaded, the macro `\translate` changes its meaning and becomes a set of instructions for *printing* the week day name. And it does it in a non expandable way, so it cannot be used in the argument of `\StrLeft`.

Here's a workaround that uses only expandable commands.

```
\documentclass[english,ngerman]{article}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{translator}
\usepackage{xstring}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{xpatch}

\usetikzlibrary{calendar}
\usedictionary{months}

\let\xpgfcalendarweekdayname\pgfcalendarweekdayname
\xpatchcmd{\xpgfcalendarweekdayname}
 {\translate}
 {\xtranslate}
 {}{\ddt}
\makeatletter
\newcommand{\xtranslate}[1]{%
  \csname tr@@@\csname tr@ml@\languagename\endcsname @#1\endcsname
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

Dienstag: \pgfcalendarweekdayname{1} \StrLeft{\xpgfcalendarweekdayname{1}}{1}

\selectlanguage{english}

Tuesday: \pgfcalendarweekdayname{1} \StrLeft{\xpgfcalendarweekdayname{1}}{1}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: This is brilliant! Thank you so much -- I'm afraid I still can't wrap my head around expansions much.